Nestjs GraphQL exceptions by union types
I'm using union type types to return schema based exceptions from Nestjs GraphQL API.
export const CityUpdateUnion = createUnionType({
  name: 'CityUpdateUnion',
  types: () => [City, BaseException, CityNotFoundException] as const,
  resolveType(value) {
    if (value instanceof CityNotFoundException) {
      return CityNotFoundException;
    } else if (value instanceof BaseException) {
      return BaseException;
    }
    return City;
  },
});

and, in the schema I have;
union CityUpdateUnion = City | BaseException | CityNotFoundException

updateCity(input: UpdateCityInput!): CityUpdateUnion!

which is nice.
There are some exception cases not specific to a resolver, such as Unauthorized Exception or GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED . Should I add those generic exceptions to my union types as well? Would that bloat the union types too much? Although I like having exceptions on the schema, what would be the sane approach?
